# javascript reg exp

Tags: javascript, regex

im new student... currently im trying to find out how to get this regExp , sorry for first , so hard to explain.

i want regExp for:

```
ABCD //which given true in exact sequence

input : AOOBCOODOO or ACCCBCOODOO
output: aOObcOOdOO  or aCCCbcOOdOO    //A,B,C,D in order get lower-cased

input : AYYBTTCDDD , output : aYYbTTcdD ;
input : ASRBB // return false no 'C' 'D'
input : AABBCCDD , output : aAbBcCdD
```

will return true , and lowercase for 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' , and the 2nd alphabet which same won't be changed

```
//the A,B,C,D change to lower case.
```

here's what i have tried :

```
    var rE = /A.*[B].*[C].*[D]/g;   //so i can get exact-order for regex 
//which  are A >> B >> C >> D
```

so i want to return the words but the `exact alphabet` will be different (lowercase);

Comment: `String.toLowerCase()` is not good enough?

Comment: @nicovank and everything get lower case too ? i just want the exact alphabet , that's why using regex ?

Comment: You will probably have to write some kind of parser

Comment: It will change all uppercase letters to lowercase ones, and not change any numbers.

Comment: A few more examples in "input : XXX, output: YYY" format would be great.

Comment: @nicovank it's not a number ADDBDDCDD will return aDDbDDcdD

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak done sir

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/1xcrpo2x/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  thankyou sir, it got the hints.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  may I know what are  `$0,$1,$2,$3` ? so i can learn what re they called ?

Comment: Does that piece of code work for you? Shall I post an answer?

Comment: @DellWatson I've posted an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no , my code was completed , but i just want to learn what's the meaning of `return $0$1...`  , just give me the reference or the name of em so I could google it.

Comment: Search for *MDN `replace`* at Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```js
function extract(input, words) {
  // Any array or string "words" argument is acceptable
  if(typeof words === 'string') {
    // Lets convert words to array if it is single string
    words = words.split('');
  }
  
  // We only accept string inputs and array words
  if(typeof input !== 'string' || !Array.isArray(words)) {
    throw new SyntaxError('input not string or words not in expected format');
  }
  
  // Lets create a regex which extracts all words and others
  var reg = new RegExp(
    '^(.*?)' + 
    words.map(w => `(${w})`).join('(.*?)') +
    '(.*)$', 
    'i'
  );
  
  // If input matches then let replace it, otherwise it will return false
  return reg.test(input) && input.replace(reg, function() {
    // first argument is $0 (matched input)
    // last couple arguments are index and input
    
    // other arguments are groups
    // Even indexed groups are our non matched parts
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length - 2);
    
    return args.map((a, idx) => ((idx % 2) && a.toLowerCase()) || a)
      .join('');
  });
}
                                          
console.log(extract('AABBBBBBCCDD', 'ABCD'))
console.log(extract('ASRBB', 'ABCD'))
console.log(extract('aAAaaBBbbbbBBcccDDddd', 'ABCD'))
console.log(extract('HOWHJJHJHHABOUTKKHHOTHERS', ['HOW', 'ABOUT', 'OTHERS']));
```